# Order by highest group - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

This code here groups a Users friends by highschool name.

```
<% @user.friends.group_by(&:highschool_name).map do |hsname, friends| %>
<% next if hsname.blank? %>
<div class="contentbox">
    <div class="box-header">
        <h3><%= hsname %></h3>
    </div>
    <ul class="friends-list">
        <% friends.map do |friend| %>
           <li><%= image_tag(friend.image) %>
        <% end %> 
    </ul> 
</div>
<% end %>
```

But it groups with out any order, I would like to order by highste value. Showing the highest group first and down. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`group_by` gives you a hash in return. You can sort on count of values before iterating:

```
groups = @user.friends.group_by(&:highschool_name)
sorted_groups = groups.sort_by{|key, values| values.count}.reverse
sorted_groups.each do |hsname, friends|
  # do your thing here
end
```

Comment: great! It does sort but it dosent show the highest group first.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
@user.friends.group(:highschool_name).order("highschool_name DESC")
```